# I want to know the answer to this checkbox issue in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, local-storage

I saw this excellent post: [How to get persist checkbox checked on page refresh in React JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66466711/how-to-get-persist-checkbox-checked-on-page-refresh-in-react-js)

but when the it came to the answer the link for the answers sandbox was "broken" or disabled... and I really could need a good answer on how they fixed the refresh issue on https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-noether-7ze1r?file=/src/App.js.

if its not to much to ask.

Answer (score 1):

It's explained in the comments. The problem was that the peopleInfoValue was fetched and updated properly, but it was not used in rendering. When the page loaded it used the default state, not the stored state.